# How to filter by multiple related entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a - perhaps a little embarrassing - question that I can't figure out the answer to. I have the following entities:

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I configured the relationship to be many-to-many using the fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("PostId");
        m.MapRightKey("TagId");
        m.ToTable("PostTags");
    });
```

I want to filter the posts by a list of tags (only return posts that have all the tags specified):

```
context.Posts.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t)))
```

Where `tags` is a list of user-specified tags and my `Tag` entity has its `Equals` method overridden to be based on the `Id` property. But when I run the query I get a `NotSupportedException`:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Plog.Domain.Plog.Tag'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

How can I make this work in a way that is also reasonably performant?

Comment: I'm assuming tags is a list of `Tag`? if so, that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use tags as a list of `Tag` in your query. `.Contains()` won't work with classes as they aren't constants. Convert `tags` to a list of `Guid` (since you're checking on `Id`). i.e.

```
context.Posts.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t.Id)))
```

For performance, you can put indexes on the tables. That's my 2 cents. Might be better ways today, but the above has worked out ok for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work, I get the same exception (which is understandable because `Guid` isn't a primitive type).

Comment: Ok that is surprising (I did it like that just the other day). Can you update the question with how you defined `tags`?

Comment: I isolated the problem in a separate solution and your solution worked. The exception was completely unrelated to it. Thanks for your help!